# Why does Gradle disregard release{} and implement a rule on debug build as well?

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am not sure if this happened before, but I think it happened after the recent updates of Android Studio and its Gradle.

Namely, I am trying to set the output path of the release APK. So I made a code like this

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        signingConfig signingConfigs.config

        def outputPathName = "./apk-release.apk"
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = file(outputPathName)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will move APK from its default location (`/build/outputs/apk`) and place it next to the `build.gradle` file.

However, the `release{}` is being disregarded and Android Studio moves debug build to this location as well also renaming it. So either I create signed APK or press debug icon to test the debug release, the APK is being moved and renamed. And it should stay inside its default location, right?

Why is this happening? A bug inside Android Studio Gradle or a bug in my code?

NOTE: I noticed that the same happens in my other project in which I create a custom name for the APK. It will also rename debug APK and in the same manner disregard `release{}`.

Android Studio version: 1.3. Preview 5

Comment: It's not disregarding `release{}`; it's that it doesn't work the way you expect it to. In configuration phase of the build, it executes all of the script in that block regardless of what kind of build you're doing; in fact, during configuration phase, it doesn't even know yet. It's not until it gets to execution phase where it starts running tasks that the build type is more conventionally known.

Comment: @ScottBarta Thanks Scot. Yes, I understood it wrongly as I was not aware of the execution time. I thought it's during the build process. CommonsWare explained it well as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the release{} is being disregarded

Not really. **Every line** of code in `build.gradle` is executed when the script is processed.

Gradle scripts are not there to execute code at build time. They are there to define the object model of the build process. In Android Studio, Gradle scripts are not read in and interpreted at build time; they are read in when the project opens or when you "Sync Project with Gradle Files". It is that object model that populates things like the Build Variants view.

The `release` closure is not saying "this is only stuff that should be done on a release build". It merely says "hey, anything you can't recognize, like `minifyEnabled`, see if that's a property or method or something on this here `release` object". You could write the beginning portion of your `release` closure like this:

```
buildTypes {
    release.minifyEnabled false
    release.proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    release.signingConfig signingConfigs.config
}
```

or even:

```
   buildTypes.release.minifyEnabled false
   buildTypes.release.proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
   buildTypes.release.signingConfig signingConfigs.config
```

if you wanted.

That's why you will usually see that sort of `applicationVariants` loop at the end of `android {}`, as (I think) `applicationVariants` is part of the Gradle for Android plugin DSL, and it will iterate over all application variants.

So, if you only want to affect the `release` build, in your loop, check the `variant` for its build type:

```
    def outputPathName = "./apk-release.apk"
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def name = variant.buildType.name

        if (name.equals(com.android.builder.core.BuilderConstants.DEBUG)) {
            return; // Skip debug builds.
        }

        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            output.outputFile = file(outputPathName)
        }
    }
```

(there's probably a slicker way of filtering this, but this is what I've been using...)

Comment: WOW, WOW, WOW!!! Each time I think I know something, you put me to the ground and I know how vast my ignorance is :). Thanks a lot!